# Using two elements for xsl:key key

Tags: xslt, xslkey

I know that if I have an XML file like this:

```
 <persons>
   <class name="English">
        <person name="Tarzan" id="050676"/>
        <person name="Donald" id="070754"/>
        <person name="Dolly" id="231256"/>
   </class>
   <class name="Math">
        <person name="Winston" id="050677"/>
        <person name="Donald"  id="070754"/>
        <person name="Fred"    id="231257"/>
   </class>
 </persons>
```

I can define a key in an XSL file like this:

```
 <xsl:key name="preg" match="person" use="@id"/>
```

where I'm using id as the key.  However, Donald is listed twice, but is only in one place in preg.

Suppose I want him listed twice in preg.  That is, I want to make the class name be part of the identifier.  Basically, I want preg to have keys that are equivalent to ordered pairs: (class-name, id).  How do I do that (using XSLT 1.0)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Concatenate the keys?  How about

```
use="concat(../@name, @id)"
```

This would serve to keep them separate in the index.  You'd of course have to use the same key to retrieve them.  To avoid any ambiguity I'd also include a delimiter that won't occur in either subkey, as in

```
use="concat(../@name, '|', @id)"
```

This is the recommended approach in Michael Kay's XSLT2 reference.